# nghttp2 server handle multiple requests from a client on different threads

Tags: rest, http2, nghttp2

I am using `nghttp2` to implement a RESTful API server. I have defined two GET APIs:
`/api/ping` and `/api/wait`. While the response to the former is sent immediately, the server does some processing before responding to the latter. I allotted 4 threads to the server.

From a client (also implemented using `nghttp2`), I made a connection to the server and made the API calls one by one, `/api/wait` first followed by `/api/ping`. I observed using Wireshark that the two GET requests are sent over two different TCP packets. However, until the server completes processing of the `/api/wait`, it does not not process `/api/ping`, although it has other threads available.

I established two TCP connections from the client and made the two API calls on the different connections and the server processed those in parallel.

Does this mean that `nghttp2` processes one TCP connection **exclusively** on one thread and requests from one TCP connection are processed sequentially **by design**? Is there any setting in `nghttp2` to circumvent this? This may be a good feature for a web application (processing requests sequentially) but not an API server where APIs are independent of each other.

Comment: is your code available somewhere?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soumyakantiroychowdhury/d7104c4c83ad2da19c22416460582dc1

Comment: Thanks, spawning a thread from the wait handler should work, something like the following: https://gist.github.com/deweerdt/37bfe15569b8eb96c5799692e0b376a0

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. But won't it have performance issues for creating and destroying threads? Moreover, this method would require me to know which APIs are slower in order to delegate the task to a different thread.

Comment: > But won't it have performance issues for creating and destroying threads?

Yes, you would need a thread pool to avoid those.

> Moreover, this method would require me to know which APIs are slower in order to delegate the task to a different thread

That is true. However, the trade off is done for performance, if streams were handled by different threads, you would have to add locking to synchronize the different threads writing to the same underlying TCP connection.

Comment: Agreed with your points. Thanks again.